# using std::find with a predicate

Tags: c++, vector, find, predicate

I want to use `std::find` function along with a predicate (not sure if I use the correct word). Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  typedef pair< int, vector<int> > way;
  typedef pair< int, int > index;
  typedef pair< index, vector<way> > entry;
  vector< entry > table;

  void bar() 
  {
     vector<int> v1;
     v1.push_back(1);
     v1.push_back(2);

     way w = make_pair( 1, v1 );
     vector<way> v2;
     v2.push_back(w);

     index id = make_pair( 10, 20 );
     entry en = make_pair( id, v2 );
     table.push_back( en );
  }
  void insert()
  {
     index new_id = make_pair( 10, 20 );
     if ( find(table.begin(), table.end(), new_id) != table.end() ) {
        // index matched in the table
        // then I will push back a new pair (way)
        // to the second part of the entry
     }
  }
};
int main()
{
  foo f;
  f.bar();
  f.insert();
  return 0; 
}
```

As you can see, `find()` should search the `table` based on the first element in each entry. Right now, it says that `==` is not overloaded to compare a `pair`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
...
if(find_if(table.begin(), table.end(), [&new_id](const entry &arg) { 
                                           return arg.first == new_id; }) != ...)
```

**EDIT:** If you don't have C++11 (and therefore no lambdas), you have to create a custom functor (function or function object) to do the comparison of `entry::first` with the searched `index`:

```
struct index_equal : std::unary_function<entry,bool>
{
    index_equal(const index &idx) : idx_(idx) {}
    bool operator()(const entry &arg) const { return arg.first == idx_; }
    const index &idx_;
};

...
if(find_if(table.begin(), table.end(), index_equal(new_id)) != ...)
```

**EDIT:** Since an `index` is just a pair of `int`s, you may also just capture it by value than const reference, to keep the code clearer and more concise, but it doesn't really matter either.

Comment: this `find_if` is a statement. Isn't there any return value? what happen if there is a match?

Comment: @mahmood Do you mean the `struct`. Technically in C++98 it cannot be function local I think, so you make it a member type of `foo` (to have implicit access to `foo`'s members. But practically this usually doesn't matter and you can just define this struct inside the `insert` function. Of course all this is only needed if you don't have C++11 lambdas, in which case you can just use the short and streamlined first code snippet.

Comment: @mahmood Of course this whole `find_if` is to replace your existing `find` call in your `if` statement, c'mon. It has the same return value as `find`.

Comment: I understand. What I am asking is, how can I use the output of find_if? I mean where should I put my next codes (the comments). But I can not use `if (find_if(...)) {}`

Comment: @mahmood Ah ok, you can just assign the return value to an iterator, check this iterator in the `if` statement, and then inside the block use it, since it points to the found element. `auto iter = find_if; if(iter != table.end) iter->second = ...;`.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11, you can use also [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
if (std::any_of(table.cbegin(), table.cend(),
                [&new_id](const entry &arg) { return arg.first == new_id; }))
```