# How to get an index number by struct id in vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct person{
    int p_id;
};
std::vector<person> people;

person tmp_person;
tmp_person.p_id = 1;
people.push_back(tmp_person);


person tmp_person2;
tmp_person2.p_id = 2;
people.push_back(tmp_person2);


person tmp_person3;
tmp_person3.p_id = 3;
people.push_back(tmp_person3);
```

How can I find a index number of vector **people** by the person's id.
For example, how can I get a index number of a person who has p_id 2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return index of struct position in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553361/return-index-of-struct-position-in-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to find the element. This returns an iterator to the element. And if you really want to know the index use [`std:distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance):

```
int id_to_find = 1;

std:size_t found_idx = std::distance(
    std::begin(people),
    std::find_if(std::begin(people), std::end(people),
                [=] (const person& p) { return p.p_id == id_to_find; })
    );
```

But you should really use iterators in C++ unless you have a good reason to want indexes.

Answer (score 0):

**Search** in the vector using **for loop**.

```
for(int i=0;i<people.size();i++){
    if(people[i].p_id == 2){
        return i
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using find_if

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::find_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector
int val=2;
struct person{
    int p_id;
};
bool isValue (struct person i) {
  return ((i.p_id)==val);
}

int main () {
  std::vector<struct person> people;

  person tmp_person;
  tmp_person.p_id = 1;
  people.push_back(tmp_person);


  person tmp_person2;
  tmp_person2.p_id = 2;
  people.push_back(tmp_person2);


  person tmp_person3;
  tmp_person3.p_id = 3;
  people.push_back(tmp_person3);

  std::vector<person>::iterator it = std::find_if (people.begin(), people.end(), isValue);
  std::cout << "The index of value is " << it-people.begin() << '\n';


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::find_if (people.begin(), people.end(), isValue);` doesn't compile. `isValue` is not a valid predicate here, it has the wrong parameters.

Comment: No! Don't use global `val`!

Comment: How should I do it without hard coding the val?

Comment: Use a lambda with capture. Or create an equivalent struct.